# if function inside table in php

Tags: php

I am new in php, please help me solve my problem.

I have a table that is generated using php. In the `Download` column of my table I have a condition to check if certain file exists. If yes, then generate its hyperlink for download.

Please check my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "view") {
    $output = '';
    $data = $admin->read();
    if ($admin->totalRowCount() > 0) {
        $output .= '<table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr class="text-center">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>download</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $output .= '<tr class="text-center text-secondary">
            <td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['nama'] . '</td>
            <td>

               //this is my if file exists function, how to make it work??
               if (file_exists( __DIR__ . "upload/' . $row['nama'] . '.xlsx")) {
                      echo "<a href="upload/' . $row['nama'] . '.xlsx" download>tes</a>";
                    }else {
                      echo "not exists";
                    }

            </td></tr>';
        }
        $output .= '</tbody></table>';
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo '<h3 class="text-center text-secondary mt-5">:( Empty!</h3>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error that you are getting

Comment: My wild guess is the missing `/` in path. To verify this do two things. Change `echo "not exists";` to `echo "not exists" .  __DIR__ . "upload/'.$row['nama'].'.xlsx";` to see what path you are trying to invoke. Then change to `/upload` (add slash before upload)

Comment: What's your question about this code? Anything not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just needs proper code structuring and quotes arrangements. Also the string concatenation in `$output` was just not properly correct / formatted, which is already mentioned by `kerbh0lz` in his answer.

However here is your full code.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "view") {
    $output = '';
    $data = $admin->read();
    if ($admin->totalRowCount() > 0) {
        $output .= '<table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr class="text-center">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>download</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $output .= '<tr class="text-center text-secondary">
            <td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['nama'] . '</td>
            <td>';
            //this is my if file exists function, how to make it work??
            if (file_exists(__DIR__ . 'upload/' . $row['nama'] . '.xlsx')) {
                $output .= '<a href="upload/' . $row['nama'] . '.xlsx" download>test</a>';
            } else {
                $output .= "not exists";
            }
            $output .= '</td></tr>';
        }
        $output .= '</tbody></table>';
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo '<h3 class="text-center text-secondary mt-5">:( Empty!</h3>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to end your `$output .= ...` line from before first, then resume `$output .= '</td></tr>';` in the line after your `if`. Also, change the `echo` inside your `if` to `$output .= ...`

```
$output .= '<tr class="text-center text-secondary">
    <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['nama'].'</td>
    <td>'; // end $output here

if (file_exists( __DIR__ . "upload/" . $row['nama'] . ".xlsx")) {
    $output .= '<a href="upload/' . $row['nama'] . '.xlsx" download>tes</a>';
} else {
    $output .= "not exists";
}

// resume $output from here
$output .= '</td></tr>';
```

Edit: also fixed the quotes in your `if`